# Leaflet.js How to stop on map evnet

Tags: leaflet

I am calling a function when the user has panned the map with:

```
    $('#updateTheMap').click(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('updateMap').checked) {
            // stop the the dragend event...
        }
        else {
            map.on('dragend', function() {
                sortBinis(simpleFilterSql);
            });
        }
    });
```

But I can not figure out how to end this event?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what "end this event" means?

Comment: When the event map.on('dragend', function() {}); is called, then each time the map is panned the function sortBinis(simpleFilterSql); is executed. I want this event to end/stop calling the sortBinis function when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
var updateTheMap = true;
$('#updateTheMap').click(function() {
    updateTheMap =  document.getElementById('updateMap').checked;
});
map.on('dragend', function() {
    if (updateTheMap) sortBinis(simpleFilterSql);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If by 'end this event' you mean 'remove the event listener' you can use map.off()

```
function onDragend(e) { sortBinis(simpleFilterSql); }

$('#updateTheMap').click(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('updateMap').checked) {
            map.off('dragend', onDragend); 
        }
        else {
            map.on('dragend', onDragend); 
        }
    });
```